# python numpy transpose not working as expected

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, transpose

I want to transpose a matrix by different means, and I am not successful. I first tried this

```
import numpy as np

z = self.mat 

print len(z), len(z[0])
print   '  z  ' + str(z) + ' ztr  ' + str(np.transpose(z))
```

with `self.mat` a matrix (array of array, [[...],[...],...]).

Printed things in console does not correspond to what I expect: z and np.transpose(z) are the same.

I have tried with `zip(*self.mat)`. This time, problem is that from 60*15 original matrix, I obtain a 15*69 transposed matrix.

could you think of a solution?
thanks

Comment: Please post a full (functional) example code and the complete output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on this

I used the following to transpose matrix and keep the data structure type 'array of array' (not array of tuples):

```
 z = [list(x) for x  in zip(*z)]
```